# Nested Parallel performance question

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have question.

Are there any benefits of using Parallel.Invoke inside of another Parallel.ForEach?

Here is my code:

```
    Parallel.ForEach(yearMonths,
                     () => new List<DJVSStatsCo>(),
                     (yearMonth, loopState, localDjvsStatsCo) =>
                         {
                             var coVintageCounter = 0;
                             var coExitsCounter = 0;
                             var coExtant = 0;

                             Parallel.Invoke(() =>
                                             coVintageCounter = globalData.ValuationEventsPit.
                                                                    Where(x => x.FirstRoundYearMonth <= yearMonth).
                                                                    Select(x => x.CompanyId).Distinct().Count(),
                                             () =>
                                             coExitsCounter = globalData.ValuationEventsPit.
                                                                  Where(x => x.ExitDate != null && x.ExitDateYearMonth == yearMonth).
                                                                  Select(x => x.CompanyId).Distinct().Count(),
                                             () =>
                                             coExtant = globalData.ValuationEventsPit.
                                                            Where(x => x.FirstRoundYearMonth <= yearMonth && (x.ExitDate == null || x.ExitDateYearMonth > yearMonth)).
                                                            Select(x => x.CompanyId).Distinct().Count()
                                 );

                             localDjvsStatsCo.Add(new DJVSStatsCo(yearMonth, coVintageCounter, coExtant, coExitsCounter));

                             return localDjvsStatsCo;
                         },
                     x =>
                         {
                             lock (locker)
                             {
                                 djvsStatsCos.AddRange(x);
                             }
                         });
```

I have about 50K records and my machine has 2 core processors and calculating calc time I am getting almost the same result.  So my question is are there any benefits of using Parallel inside of Parallel?  What is the best practice for this?

Thanks a lot.

Sincerely,
Vlad.

Comment: If you are getting the same throughput in both cases then there would be no reason to complicate the code with the `Parallel.Invoke`. In other words, you don't get bonus points for making something *more* parallel if *less* parallel already saturates the CPU...sometimes you even lose points!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, there's *probably* no benefit. There *could* be a benefit in the case where you have relatively few "outer" jobs, but potentially many "inner" jobs.

On the other hand, it also depends on what those three jobs are doing. If they're essentially asynchronous tasks (e.g. on the database) which can be executed in parallel, then sure... but if they're *local* CPU-intensive tasks, then you're probably just going to give extra work to the scheduler for no real benefit.

Given the look of your code, it strikes me that you could quite possibly benefit from performing a single query (or maybe three) and grouping by `yearMonth` though...

Answer (score 4):

Since the parallelism of the outer loop already keeps your CPUs busy (50k elements) there is little benefit in introducing parallelism *within* the loop. In the interest of readability I would remove the `Parallel.Invoke` call to simplify your code.

Comment: Assuming the sub tasks are purely computational.